# PHP form requires two submit button clicks to disappear

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, session

I am using session variable to hide a log in form after user logs in. Here are first two lines from the PHP webpage

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Now,this is the logout button which appears after a user has logged in but take disappears only after two clicks

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Hey, <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user'].''; ?></p>
<input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Logout'){
session_destroy();
}?>
```

Here is code snippet from login form

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
<form method="post" action="">
```

After succesful login I set
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $memberinfo['USER'];

Why do I have to click two times to keep get the forms work as expected?

**EDIT**
Here is the complete code with HTML and Javascript stripped out

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
    if($passkey=$_GET['passkey']){
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM unactivated WHERE code ='$passkey'");
    if($result){
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1){
    $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $user=$rows['USER'];
    $email=$rows['EMAIL'];
    $password=$rows['PASSWORD'];
    $password=$mysqli->real_escape_string(hash_hmac('sha256',$password, 'c#haRl891', true));
    if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO member ( USER, EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$password')"))
    {
    echo "Your account has been activated";
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM unactivated WHERE code = '$passkey'");
    }}}
    else {
    echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
    }}?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Alex Bruno (for Sign Up)" />
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required />
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Strong Password" required />
    <p>Enter valid email to get a login link.</p>
    <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875; float:right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Register'){
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['user'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['email'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from member WHERE EMAIL ='$email'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows == 0)
    {
    $code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO unactivated (CODE, USER, EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$code', '$user', '$email', '$password')");
    $to=$email;
    $subject="Please verify your Sign Up";
    $header="from: 8mags <contact@8mags.com>";
    $message="You or someone else used this email address to sign up for 8mags. If you did not do it ignore the message.\n";
    $message.="To verify your account please click on the link below\n";
    $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?passkey='.$code.'';
    $message.=$url;
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    if($sentmail){
    echo 'Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.';
    }}
    echo 'Email already registered!';
    }}
    if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Login'){
    $password=$mysqli->real_escape_string(hash_hmac('sha256',$password, 'c#haRl891', true));
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from member WHERE EMAIL = '$email' AND PASSWORD = '$password'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($rows==1)
    {
    $memberinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $memberinfo['USER'];
    }
    else{
    echo 'Entered Password and Email Combination is wrong!';
    }}?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo 'style="display:none;"'; else echo 'style="display:block;"';?>/>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <p>Hey, <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user'].''; ?></p>
    <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Logout'){
    }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroy session should come at the very top of the page *[EDIT]* followed by a redirect with a `header()` to reload the page (as suggested by, and who reminded me of..) by *DarkBee*.

Also, here is what I would recommend to you for your page. Everything is notated:

**functions.php** (new page containing your main functions)

```
<?php
    // You should make these functions and on
    // a separate page that you include
    function Login($checkpass, $checkemail, $mysqli)
        {
                $email      =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($checkemail);
                $password   =   $mysqli->real_escape_string(hash_hmac('sha256',$checkpass, 'c#haRl891', true));
                $query      =   $mysqli->query("SELECT * from member WHERE EMAIL = '$email' AND PASSWORD = '$password'");
                $rows       =   mysqli_num_rows($query);

                if($rows == 1) {
                    $memberinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                    $_SESSION['login']  =   true;
                    $_SESSION['user']   =   $memberinfo['USER'];
                    return true;
                }
        // Return false if failed
        return false;
    }

    function Register($mysqli)
        {
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['user'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['email'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['password'])) {
                $user       =   $_POST['user'];
                $email      =   $_POST['email'];
                $password   =   $_POST['password'];
                $user       =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);
                $email      =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
                $password   =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
                $query      =   $mysqli->query("SELECT * from member WHERE EMAIL ='$email'");
                $rows       =   mysqli_num_rows($query);

                if ($rows == 0) {
                    $code       =   md5(uniqid(rand()));
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO unactivated (CODE, USER, EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$code', '$user', '$email', '$password')");
                    $to         =   $email;
                    $subject    =   "Please verify your Sign Up";
                    $header     =   "from: 8mags <contact@8mags.com>";
                    $message    =   "You or someone else used this email address to sign up for 8mags. If you did not do it ignore the message.\n";
                    $message    .=  "To verify your account please click on the link below\n";
                    $url        =   "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?passkey='.$code.'';
                    $message    .=  $url;

                    // Return success
                    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return fail by default
            return false;
        }

    function FetchPassKey($mysqli)
        {
            // This part is a bit scary, you are not binding or sanitizing this.
            // It's open to sql injection attacks
            $passkey    =   $_GET['passkey'];
            $result     =   $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM unactivated WHERE code ='$passkey'");
            if($result) {
                    $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if($count==1){
                        $rows       =   mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                        $user       =   $rows['USER'];
                        $email      =   $rows['EMAIL'];
                        $password   =   $rows['PASSWORD'];
                        $password   =   $mysqli->real_escape_string(hash_hmac('sha256',$password, 'c#haRl891', true));

                        if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO member ( USER, EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$password')")) {
                            $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM unactivated WHERE code = '$passkey'");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            return false;
        }
    ?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    function DBConnect($db_hostname = 'host',$db_username = 'username',$db_password = 'password',$db_database = 'dbname')
        {
            // Database 
            $mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            return $mysqli;
        }

    // Start session
    session_start();
    $mysqli =   DBConnect(); ?>
```

**index.php** (Whatever name this page is, I picked index.php)

```
    // Make a db function
    include_once('config.php');
    // Include the functions that run this page actions
    include_once('functions.php');
    // If logging out, destroy session
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Logout script
        if($_POST['submit'] == 'Logout') {
                session_destroy();
                header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                exit;
            }
        // Run your login script
        elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'Login')
            $valid  =   Login($_POST['password'],$_POST['email'],$mysqli);
        elseif($_POST['submit'] = 'Register')
            $registered =   Register($mysqli);
    }      

    // You are doing an equals here, should be double equal ==
    // or it will always be true
    if(isset($_GET['passkey']) && !empty($_GET['passkey'])){
        echo (FetchPassKey($mysqli) == true)? "Your account has been activated":"Wrong Confirmation code";
    }

    // Just don't print it to page
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
    <div style=" display: inline-block;" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Alex Bruno (for Sign Up)" />
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Strong Password" required />
            <p>Enter valid email to get a login link.</p>
            <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
            <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875; float:right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php }

    // Just echo the results of your register validate function
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Register')
        echo ($registered == true)?  'Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.':'Email already registered!';

    // Just echo the results of your validation here but assign and check at top.
    if(isset($valid) && $valid == false)
        echo 'Entered Password and Email Combination is wrong!';

    // Just display if logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:block;">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p>Hey, <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['user'].''; ?></p>
            <input style="border: none; padding: 8px 15px; background: #BAFF00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #757875;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: But I am destroying it after user clicks on Logout. How is this one different?

Comment: Because you are destroying the session after you print the `$_SESSION['login']` to the page so it appears you have not logged out. You will get the same result if you refresh rather than click the logout button again.

Comment: I got this error Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Comment: Did you set it up exactly as written above? First `session_start()`, then check for logout, then destroy?

Comment: Yes, the error is on line 251, the line where I destroy it in my logout form

Comment: You don't need to destroy it there if you destroy it at the top of the page. It will have already been destroyed by that point.

Comment: So, should I just remove this code completely <?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Logout'){
session_destroy();
}?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69017/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-rasclatt).

Comment: Yes, remove it from the 251 line, replace it with what I have above.

Comment: Ok, see my edits. The main ones are where the session stuff is located at the top

Comment: Should I paste all the code in a single different page and include it in my webpage?

Comment: What you should do is make 2 new pages. One that is functions.php and the other whatever it's already called. Just back up your current one incase you want to bail and go back to what you had.

Comment: I created a separate functions.php page and included it in my other webpage named index.php.  The form on login shows email password mis-match now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I see why. There is no $password parameter in the  function. One second I willl fix

Comment: Ok I updated it in the `function Login($checkpass,$mysqli)` function and on the index page where it's applied: `$valid  =   Login($_POST['password'],$mysqli);` Copy that whole function over the other one.

Comment: Also, I am not 100% sure where you are getting that `$password` so I got it from `$_POST['password']`. The code is the same as yours, only I split it out into functions, so you may have dependent variables floating around that needs some modification.

Comment: I was also using $_POST['password'] to get password value. Could the position where I put include code for functions.php result in any error?

Comment: Go into the chat room again to discuss.

Comment: @Rasclatt : `Destroy session needs to come at the very top of the page.`, This is not true... You could do a `header location` after destroying the session

Comment: @DarkBee Yeah that is true. That is a good idea. Now that you mention it, I think that is what normally do to get my personal stuff to work...I have to reload on a `header()` redirect. Man, I have been slaving away with this...